# Let n>30. Then prove there exists a natural number $ 1< m\leq n$ such that $(n,m)=1$ and $m$ is not prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n>30$. Then prove there exists a natural number $1<m\leq n$ such that $(n,m)=1$ and $m$ is not prime.

$(m,n)$ denotes the  greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you requiring $n\gt30$?

Comment: this is not true for $n<30$

Comment: @elham It is definitely true, as stated, for $n<30$.

Comment: Perhaps you intended to include the condition $m\lt n$ and forgot?

Comment: @joriki Ah, that's probably it.

Comment: Note, as stated, $m=1$ works for all $n$. $1$ is a natural number, $1$ is not prime, and $(1,n)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I took the liberty to make the inequality $1<m$ strict, to avoid trivial answers.

Answer (score 4):

Since $30=2\cdot3\cdot5$ and $2^2,3^2,5^2<30$ it's enough to consider the case $30\mid n$ (if not take $m=2^2$ or $m=3^2$ or $m=5^2$). Assume that to be the case.

Let $p$ be the smallest prime with $p\nmid n$. Then $(n,p^2)=1$ and $p^2<n$.
 This is because $31$ is the largest [primorial prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime) less than the next prime(of the primes in the primorial) squared (see [this](http://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/31.html) and for a proof Hagen von Eitzen's answer).
 Take $m=p^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_k$ be the largest prime for which $n$ is divisible by $p_k\#=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot\ldots\cdot p_{k-1}\cdot p_k$.
Clearly $(n,m)=1$ if we let $m=p_{k+1}^2$. We need to show that $m<n$.
By the Bertrand postulate, $\frac12p_k<p_{k-1}<p_k<p_{k+1}<2p_k$. 
But this follows from $m<4p_k^2$ and

- $n\ge p_k\#\ge 30p_{k-1}p_k> 15p_k^2$ if $p_k\ge 11$
- $n\ge p_k\# = 210>11^2=m$ if $p_k=7$
- $30|n$ and $n>30$, hence $n\ge 60$, and $m=49$ if $p_k=5$
- $m\le 25<n$ if $p_k\le 3$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  do you know a proof that there are an infinite number of primes?  If you find two of them not factors of $n, \dots$

Comment: You don't even need two of them...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  true enough.